# Dreamweaver WYSIWYG Drag and Drop Data bound html elements

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js, dreamweaver, wysiwyg

Two questions about Dreamweaver:

1. Is there anything in the product that enables users to move an element anywhere on a page WYSIWYG or would tables, divs, spans with justify have to be set to do that?
2. Can Dreamwever be smart about data-bound elements and view models such as those bound by Knockout.js generating code like this:  label data-bind="JobTitle"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to just edit the HTML of the elements after dragging and dropping and add the data-bind attribute. However you will most likely face issues with the HTML not being as clean as it's generated so it could be difficult to bind the data.

Comment: Independent of the element being data-bound - regarding WYIWYG, Is there anything in Dreamweaver page setup that enables us to move an element (like a label or button) anywhere on a page, or do we have to set up tables, divs, spans etc to be able to position elements?

Comment: You can absolute position an element if you wish. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp